# How to find values from one table to limit other table?

Tags: sql

I have a table of answers to questions.
this table includes

ID, idOfQuestion, and User

the questions table includes

ID, message, etc..

what i want to do is find a certain user, and then find all the idOfQuestions that he or she has answered, then i want to search in the questions table all the questions that DON'T HAVE the same idOfQuestions from the first query.

note: ifOfQuestion in answer = ID in question

and this should all be in sql

Comment: Hello Robert, which SQL? Could you please provide the code you have until now. Sounds like a very basic question, you could resolve with a little bit of reading in the documentation of your SQL Software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don;t know i had understand your question clear but take a look at this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM QuestionTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
    (SELECT IDOFQuestion as ID FROM tableQuestion WHERE USER = 'USERHERE')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find which questions they have not answered, you can use an outer JOIN

e.g.

```
SELECT q.*
FROM Questions q
    LEFT JOIN Answers a ON q.ID = a.idOfQuestion AND a.User = 'UserIdValue'
WHERE a.idOfQuestion IS NULL
```

Using a LEFT JOIN with the WHERE...IS NULL like this, means it will only return Questions where there is no matching row in Answers table for that Question + UserId

Answer (score 0):

And the NOT EXISTS variant:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM Questions q
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL FROM Answers a 
 WHERE q.ID = a.idOfQuestion AND a.User = 'UserIdValue')
```